# Can't seem to get SegmentedControl variable to display in listView

Tags: ios, swift, segmentedcontrol

I'm an extreme beginner at developing iOS applications, so be easy on me :)

I'm creating a core data base where you can add records, then view them on Xcode using Swift 3. I am having some trouble storing/displaying the segmented control for male/female. I can get the text fields and the labels to display correctly but for some reason can't get this working.

friendsViewController.swift

```
//
//  friendsViewController.swift
// 
//
//  Created by  on 11/10/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 . All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

class friendsViewController: UIViewController {
    //OUTLETS
    @IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var genderSegControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var ageStepper: UIStepper!

    //AGECOUNT
    @IBOutlet weak var ageLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var address: UITextField!

    var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    //actions
    @IBAction func ageStepperStep(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        let step = Int(sender.value) // using an integer variable
        ageLabel.text = String(step)
        // label1.text = Int(sender.value).description
        // another way without using any integer variable
    }

    //SAVE FRIEND BUTTON
    @IBAction func saveFriendBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        if firstName.text != "" && lastName.text != "" {
            var gender : String?
            if self.genderSegControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                gender = "male"
            }
            else {
                gender = "female"
            }

            let newFriend = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Friends", into: context)
            newFriend.setValue(self.firstName.text, forKey: "firstName")
            newFriend.setValue(self.lastName.text, forKey: "lastName")
            newFriend.setValue(self.address.text, forKey: "address")
            newFriend.setValue(self.ageLabel.text, forKey: "age")
            newFriend.setValue(gender!, forKey: "gender")

            //SAVE THE CONTEXT
            do {
                try context.save()
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }
        else {
            print("please enter your first and last name!")
        }
    }
} //end class
```

friendslistViewController.swift (screen that displays all records in the cells)

```
//
//  friendslistViewController.swift
// 
//
//  Created by on 11/10/17.
//  Copyright © 2017. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

class friendslistViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    //outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var userArray:[Friends] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        self.fetchData()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        //save first users data into array
        let name = userArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = name.firstName! + " " + name.lastName! + " " + name.age! + " " +
            name.gender! + " " +
            name.address!

        return cell
    }

    func fetchData(){
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        do{
            userArray = try context.fetch(Friends.fetchRequest())
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
} //end class
```

Comment: How does cell view looks like?

Comment: @Mr.Bista it is set out in rows.

https://imgur.com/a/NRCcU

Comment: I meant that how the cell elements like first name label, last name label and segment control are place in the cell view in the Xcode not in Simulator. Seems like elements are overlapping each other of the cell height is not mentioned properly.

Comment: @Mr.Bista I call it with the `cell.textLabel!.text = name.firstName! + " " + name.lastName! + " " + name.age! + " " +
            name.gender! + " " +
            name.address!` and it prints accordingly.

Comment: @Mr.Bista however, I removed the `name.gender!` bit as it started to crash.

Comment: If you change `newFriend.setValue(gender!, forKey: "gender")` to `newFriend.setValue(gender, forKey: "gender")` then what is the behaviour?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 it was like that initially, but unfortunately still doesn't work

Comment: Can you show the `Friends ` entity code?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 i created the friends entity via the `.xcdatamodeId` file. 

https://imgur.com/a/f5scg

Comment: please add `print(name.gender)` after this statement `let name = userArray[indexPath.row]` and check what it displays?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 tried both `print(name.gender)` & `print(name.gender!)` to force unwrap it. However, same result.

Comment: what does it print?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 sorry was going to edit my answer. You were too fast for me lol. it prints: `Optional("female")
Optional("female")
Optional("male")
Optional("female")
Optional("female")`

Comment: @3stud1ant3 so currently there are 5 records and it is picking them up correctly. But it is not displaying in the listView?

Comment: Ok just try this: `cell.textLabel!.text = name.gender!`  instead of `cell.textLabel!.text = name.firstName! + " " + name.lastName! + " " + name.age! + " " +
            name.gender! + " " +
            name.address!` and see what is the behaviour?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 all sorted. Don't know what the problem was but it seemed to rectified itself, weird. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: lol, weird, you are welcome :)

Comment: @3stud1ant3 would you by any chance know the answer to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751677/pass-core-data-values-into-text-fields-for-editing-saving