# Pass core data values into text fields for editing/saving

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am a novice at using Xcode and swift and still learning. I am having trouble passing core data from entities into text fields/labels which the user can then choose to edit and save the record. My aim is when the user clicks on a cell in the tableView from `friendslistViewController.swift` it then brings them to the `editViewController.swift` screen to edit and save the record. I think I need to implement the `prepareforsegue` function, but not sure how to?

**friendsViewController.swift** (initial data input)

```
//
//  friendsViewController.swift
// 
//
//  Created by on 11/10/17.
//  Copyright © 2017. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

class friendsViewController: UIViewController {

        //OUTLETS


    @IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!        
    @IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!        
    @IBOutlet weak var genderSegControl: UISegmentedControl!        
    @IBOutlet weak var ageStepper: UIStepper!

    //AGECOUNT
    @IBOutlet weak var ageLabel: UILabel!        
    @IBOutlet weak var address: UITextField!

    var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()    
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    //actions

    @IBAction func ageStepperStep(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        let step = Int(sender.value) // using an integer variable
        ageLabel.text = String(step)
        // label1.text = Int(sender.value).description
        // another way without using any integer variable
    }


    // TEST GENDER
    /*

        var gender : String
        if self.genderSegControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            gender = "male"
        }
        else {
            gender = "female"
        }
        genderLabel.text! = gender

 */

   //SAVE FRIEND BUTTON
    @IBAction func saveFriendBtn(_ sender: Any) {

        if firstName.text != "" && lastName.text != "" {               

            var gender : String?
            if self.genderSegControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                gender = "male"
            }
            else {
                gender = "female"
            }


            let newFriend = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Friends", into: context)
            newFriend.setValue(self.firstName.text, forKey: "firstName")
            newFriend.setValue(self.lastName.text, forKey: "lastName")
            newFriend.setValue(self.address.text, forKey: "address")
            newFriend.setValue(self.ageLabel.text, forKey: "age")
            newFriend.setValue(gender, forKey: "gender")

            /*let gender: String = genderSegControl.titleForSegment(at: genderSegControl.selectedSegmentIndex)!
 */


            //SAVE THE CONTEXT
            do {
                try context.save()
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }
         }
        else {
            print("please enter your first and last name!")
        }
    }

} //end class
```

**friendslistViewController.swift** (screen that displays the tableView with the cells)

```
//
//  friendslistViewController.swift
// 
//
//  Created by on 11/10/17.
//  Copyright © 2017. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

class friendslistViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    /*
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        var DestViewController : editViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! editViewController

        DestViewController.firstNameInput = name.firstName!
    }
 */

    //outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var userArray:[Friends] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()            

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        self.fetchData()
        self.tableView.reloadData()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userArray.count
    }


    //DISPLAY LISTVIEW
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        //save first users data into array
        let name = userArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = name.firstName! + " " +
            name.lastName! + ", " +
            name.age! + ", " +
            name.gender! + ", " +
            name.address!

        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        if editingStyle == .delete{

            //delete a friend
            let friend = userArray[indexPath.row]
            context.delete(friend)
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

            do{
                userArray = try context.fetch(Friends.fetchRequest())

            }catch{
                print(error)
            }

        }
        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    //fetch the data
    func fetchData(){
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        do{
            userArray = try context.fetch(Friends.fetchRequest())
        }
            //if error exists/catch it
        catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }

    //actions
 } //end class
```

**editViewController.swift** (screen that handles editing/saving)

```
//
//  editViewController.swift
// 
//
//  Created by  on 15/10/17.
//  Copyright © 2017. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

import CoreData

class editViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!        
    @IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!        
    @IBOutlet weak var ageLabel: UILabel!        
    @IBOutlet weak var address: UITextField!

    var firstNameInput = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        firstName.text = firstNameInput

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

 }
```

Comment: use `didSelectRow` method of tableview to perform segue and obviously you have to implement `prepareForSegue` method

Comment: @3stud1ant3 is it possible you can use example with reference to my code?

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you should change the names of your view controllers so they all start with capital letters (e.g. `class FriendsViewController: UIViewController`) and do the same with the file names.

Secondly, you're correct about needing to add a segue. Did you take a look at `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` in Apple's documentation?

You'll need a variable in your destination view controller (`editViewController.swift`) that you can assign the Friend object to. In your `prepare(for:sender:)` method, you'll want something like `let destinationViewController = segue.destination as! EditViewController`. You can then use that `destinationViewController` variable to access variable in your destination view controller and assign the object to it.

See how far you can get with that.

Comment: sorry I'm a bit confused. Is it possible you can use examples?

Comment: You should really do some research and try to implement something on your own before asking others to write examples for you. You should do this because it's a great way to learn, and because it's required when asking questions on SO. If you have done research, post the code you've written that doesn't work and you'll get more help.

Answer (score 0):

## Code Changes:

### 1. `friendslistViewController.swift`

```
//Change this to match your segue
private let showEditSegueID = "Edit Friend" 

private var selectedIndexPath : IndexPath?

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    
    performSegue(withIdentifier: showEditSegueID, sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
    switch segue.identifier {
        
    case .some(showEditSegueID):
        
        if let editViewController = segue.destination as? editViewController,
            let selectedIndexPath = selectedIndexPath {
            
            let friend = userArray[selectedIndexPath.row]
            editViewController.friend = friend
        }
        
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

### 2. `editViewController.swift`

```
weak var friend : Friends?
```

## Suggestions:

1. Make sure class names begin with Uppercase
2. Let the core data entity names be singular so that it represents each record it holds.
3. Learn the basics before starting to build app.
4. Learning the foundation will initially take time but will save you a lot of headaches as you go along.

## Learn:

1. Learn Swift language
2. Learn about building an app
3. Learn Core data

## References:

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-4/id881256329?mt=11
- https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-10-apps-with-swift/id1198467120
  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/coreDataOverview.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH2-SW1
- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/coreDataOverview.html

Comment: Does the code in **friendslistViewController.swift** replace my existing `override func tableView` code? Not sure where this goes

Comment: In Swift func tableView is not the entire function name. `tableView: didSelectRowAt:` is the name of the function. So this is an additional function and will not replace any of your function. I think it is best you learn the fundamentals of the Swift language